# In web Firestore get() callback is executing twice when page is reloaded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic with React and when the page is reloaded, Firestore call is returning duplicated data, since the callback executes twice.

Here's the code on the Page:

```
// View is already rendered
useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    fetchData()
});

function fetchData() {                
    getPendingCalls(userId).then((calls: any) => {
        if (calls) {
            // Show calls
            setPendingCalls(calls)                
        }            
    }) 
}
```

And here's my firebaseService with the Firebase logic:

```
export function getPendingCalls(userId: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection(collection.calls)
        .where(call.created_by, "==", userId)
        .where(call.state, "==", callState.pending)
        .orderBy(call.date)        
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {        
            const calls: Array<Call> = []
            // ... some more stuff         
            resolve(calls) 
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting pending calls: ", error);
            resolve(null)
        });
    })
}
```

Any ideas why the code inside then() is executing twice?
This only happens when the page is reloaded, if I go to another page and come back it works fine, also when I land in that page.

Thanks!

**[SOLUTION]**
After a few days I reached to the solution thanks to one guy on Firebase community in Slack. 
What happened was that even though the `useIonViewDidEnter` was calling once, it made some kind of conflict with the promise callback. So what I've been suggested to do was to use `useEffect` with no parameters instead. This is how it looks now:

```
// View is already rendered
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Hope this helps to someone else :)

Comment: Is `useIonViewDidEnter` being called twice too? If so, that might be a better thing to search for.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen. No, it's being called just once :/

Comment: In that case your `get` callback should only be called once, and I've also never seen it being called multiple times (since it's a promise, it can only resolve once). Maybe somebody else recognized it, but I'll admit it seems unlikely. I recommend putting a breakpoint in the callback, and checking where the calls are coming from.

Comment: are you 100% sure `useIonViewDidEnter` is only getting called once, components are often rendered multiple times..

Comment: Yes `useIonDidEnter` is calling just once. If I put a console.log() inside `getPendingCalls()` it just prints once, but inside `then()` twice. It's crazy. This seems to happen at the same time so that's why promise resolves anyway both times.

Comment: Ok, solved guys! Thanks to one person on the Firebase community in Slack. The thing was that `useIonDidEnter` was calling once, but despite that it make some kind of conflict with my promise callback. So what I've been suggested to do was to use `useEffect` with no parameters instead, and that fixed the problem! So now I'm not sure if I can rely on these lifecycle methods at all. Hope this helps to someone else. I will update the post with the solution.